# How to use onClick within php?

Tags: php, html

I have a php script I want to echo some html with. I keep getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

```
echo "<a onClick=\"" window.location.href='test.php'; "\" class='container'>test</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<a onClick=\"window.location.href='test.php'\" class='container'>test</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't escaping the double quotes correctly.  Each double quote that you want to escape should be written as \" .  Looks like you were trying to open and close an escaped block or something.

```
echo "<a onClick=\"" window.location.href='test.php'; "\" class='container'>test</a>";
```

vs

```
echo "<a onClick=\"window.location.href='test.php';\" class='container'>test</a>";
```